# Exchange 2010 CAS - How to make OWA front fancing?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange, exchange-2010, outlook-web-app, cas

2008 R2 SP1 - Exchange 2010 SP2 - 14.2

We had to restore our Databases due to corruption, and afterwords we had a version mismatch on the CAS and the DB Server. Ended up building a replacement CAS server same, OS, name & IP. Ran the Setup.com /M:RecoverServer from the Exchange standalone installer, then ran SP2 to be on the same version as my DB server. 
Things line up now, and I got OWA working internally, how do I get things to resolute externally? When I go to https://email.domain.com/owa it just spins and thinks, http://email.domain.com/ times out immediately. I have internal Windows DNS A records for email but they point to my DB Server .15 and my CAS is .14.

Is my issue with external MX records? My IPs would not have changed, and everything is back in the place it should be. Is it something I need to configure in IIS? I also Know I need to re-add my SSL. Any Help would be appreciated. Thanks

TLDR: How do I make OWA front Facing?

Answer (score 3):

You restored your mailbox database and that caused a version mismatch with your CAS server? That doesn't quite make sense.

Assuming that the public DNS names are unchanged and assuming that your firewall rules are unchanged and assuming that the internal ip address of the CAS server is the same as it was before then I'd suggest you check the Client Access URLs on the CAS server. If need be you can quickly configure them with the Powershell script from this page:

http://exchangeserverpro.com/powershell-script-configure-exchange-urls

Answer (score 3):

First - Exchange 2010 SP2 is no longer supported. You should be considering an upgrade as soon as possible. Start with the CAS role servers before you do the mailbox server. SP2 has problems with modern browsers, making the OWA experience less than optimal. There are also security issues.

However I would agree with Joe, my instinct is that the URLs are wrong within Exchange. Make sure that they are set correctly, along with the SSL certificate and resolve to the correct IP address. Once you have fixed it, update the server.